# What is a network monitor for tcp AND udp AND per program

Tags: networking, monitoring

There are a lot of network monitors available which I tried (nethogs, iftop, darkstat, ...). Somehow none of these fulfilled all my expectations:

- accumulation of the amount of data received instead of real-time momentary mbps
- adding both UDP and TCP (and others?) amounts of data
- output per program-name instead of per process
- preferably something lightweight, i.e. without installing a service

The best I have found until now is "nethogs -a" but that doesn't count UDP afaik. Somewhere on the web I read that with the option "-C" it should monitor UDP as well, but on ubuntu 18.04 with nethogs 0.8.5-2 this option isn't accepted.

There must be some program which does this when called with the right options, if only I knew it!

Comment: Is there an issue with Ubuntu or are you just asking for ideas on network monitoring software?

Comment: No issue with ubuntu; just asking for a tool that fulfills above expectations...